# Angular7 : How to correctly map data when subscribing to Observable if Model differ from JSON

Tags: rxjs, spring-data, observable, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am making a GET request to a REST API. My class Model differ a bit from the JSON requested, and I doesn't seem to be able to get any data : When I log into console my Model object is undefined. How do I correctly map values when subscribing to observable ?

My Model :

```
export class Signalement {

idsignalement: number;
destinataire_id: number;
idstatut: number;
iddomaine: number;
idlocalisation: number;
idtype: number;
idemetteur: number;
x: number;
y: number;
nom: string;
description: string;
descriptionlieu: string;
la_date: string;
}
```

My JSON :

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "signalements": [
            {
                "idsignalement": 1,
                "iddomaine": 1,
                "idlocalisation": 1,
                "idtype": 1,
                "idemetteur": 1,
                "idstatut": 1,
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1,
                "nom": "Postman Signalement",
                "description": "Envoie depuis postman",
                "descriptionlieu": "Sur la VM",
                "la_date": "2019-02-08T09:25:36.968+0000",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "***/signalements/1"
                    },
                    "signalement": {
                        "href": "***/signalements/1"
                    },
                    "destinataire": {
                        "href": "**/signalements/1/destinataire"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "***:8080/signalements{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://***/profile/signalements"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

My component :

```
export class SignalementsComponent implements OnInit {

signalements: Signalement[];

constructor(private signalementService: SignalementService, private messageService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSignalements();
}

getSignalements(): void {
    this.signalementService.getSignalements().subscribe((data) => {
        this.signalements = data;
    });
}
```

My Service :

```
export class SignalementService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getSignalements(): Observable<Signalement[]> {
    return this.http.get<Signalement[]>(href); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `return this.http.get<Signalement[]>(href);` because the data you receive is not a `Signalement` object.

Keep in mind that javascript is not typed, so the type indications you put in Typescript are just helpers for your coding, not actual enforced rules.

Given the schema of your answers, you should first dig in `_embedded` field. So you should do:

```
return this.http.get<Signalement[]>.pipe(map(data => data['_embedded']['signalments']));
```

You should also add checks to verify fields are indeed present and in the correct format to avoid security issues depending on the potential data source, etc.